# Why do we need to deploy Django with gunicorn?

Tags: django, web, wsgi

We can simply start a Django `server1` with `python manage.py runserver 8080`, so why do we need to deploy Django `server2` like `gunicorn myproject.wsgi`? I googled about `wsgi`, it says that `wsgi` connects between nginx and Django, but what confused me is that we can make http requests(like with postman) to `server1` and everything works well. So what's the difference?

Comment: runserver is not intended to be used in production, as documented https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver
also check
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From django [runserver documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver):

> **DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING**. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

Answer (score 0):

Like the Django Docs says:

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

So, its clear for what reason we need to use Gunicorn or other similar tools to deploy it.

Comment: But then the gunicorn [doc](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html) says `We strongly recommend using Gunicorn behind a proxy server.` 
So the actual recommendation is nginx->gunicorn->django? 
Isn't that a bit heavy?